# Is it right to use method signatures without a selector part (name)

Tags: ios, objective-c

What I mean is this:

```
 [self doSomething:att :messages :all];
```

Of course if works, but for my feeling it's hard to read and I wouldn't exactly describe it as best practice. What does Apple say about this (I only found the part where they say we should provide a selector name).

Comment: I wouldn't do this and, for what it's worth, Apple usually doesn't either. And yet, there exists [`-[CAMediaTimingFunction initWithControlPoints::::]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CAMediaTimingFunction/initWithControlPoints::::).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would Apple care how well (or poorly) you name your methods?

Is it right? Only you can decide that.

Is it good practice? No. Readable code is important. Others may need to update your code. Or most likely you will need to be able to read your own code. Make it readable. Give methods good names.